# How to transmit vectors as parameters of the onCardClick function for Hangouts Chat Bot?

Tags: google-apps-script, bots, google-chat

I need to pass vectors like "values" in Google Chat Bot's onCardClick actions, but I've only been able to transmit strings. How can I transmit other types to the action?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Could you maybe expand in what is that you have tried so far? What is your expected output? What are you getting right now? And why do you mean with vectors? Like an array?